# unable to install twilio python module in ubuntu 14.10 ,

Tags: 14.10, python-2.7

When I tried to install twilio module on my system by ...

```
anupam@JAZZ:~$ sudo pip install twilio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2876, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.4
```

I am not getting the errors,, how would I resolve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command

`sudo easy_install pip==1.5.4`

Then, install `twilio` with

`sudo pip install twilio`

Comment: thanx. @Rohith ,well I found that easyinstall was another option for me .